# ReactDOM renderToStaticMarkup renders <noscript></noscript>

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, universal

I have a universal app with React Router.

```
let html = ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
    </Provider>
);
```

The above is my React markup.
When I view my page source I see:

```
<div id="app">
    <noscript></noscript>
    <div id="home">
        <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is this `noscript` tag? Can I get rid of it?

Comment: nothing happened when i did that. another solution? anyone? :)

Comment: I think @KishoreVaishnav meant `render={true}`. See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4550

Comment: There is no such thing as `render={true}` in React or React Redux API. This was just an example in that issue.

Comment: - I deleted my comment as I don't want to confuse more. Thanks @DanAbramov

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused Redux Router with React Router in the question.
The fragment of code you are running is for React Router, so I’ll assume that’s what you’re using.

React renders `<noscript>` for components that returned `null` during rendering.
Could it be that in your route configuration, there is no component matching that particular route?
Or that your component returned `null`?

It is hard to say more without seeing the full source code.

Comment: hey Dan, thanks for directing me to the problem.
I found out that React-Helmet is causing the <noscript> tag on server rendering. is it ok to leave it as is? thanks

Comment: @MaorBane I suppose so. It's better to ask in React Helmet repo.